# show password in field in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have a form which in edit mode.
we need customers to enter password for their account here.
So first time password field comes blank. which is alright.

But after saving the form when we again take that record to edit, the password field still shows as blank. i tried to find all the values that i am getting from form array using code "$form->get('sDbPassword')". buts its showing "[value:protected] =>". its not even showing that its have some value in that field.

Need some help.
i am a newbie in zend framework 2.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to contain your code, so other users can help you without trying to guess what you did.

Comment: I can't think of any reason for a password to be pre-populated. For security the user should always type this in! (and you shouldn't be able to display it again as it should be hashed in your database!)

Comment: I agree with you all, never pre-populate the password field. But I guess, in ZF1 it use to work with `'renderPassword' => true,` in the Form. Does it still work in ZF2?

Comment: Passwords typically should be hashed, and it's the hash that's stored not the plain text password the user actually typed in. Even if you displayed the password, it would be the stored hash, and not the real password wouldn't it? (Just realised @AlexP mentioned this too)

Comment: @KunalDethe nope this option is not present in ZF2

Answer (score 2):

this is normal because zend don't populate values for form elements with type  `Zend\Form\Element\Password` for security reasons. so after your customer submit the form with the password, the value can received after form validation `$form->isValid()` with `$form->getData()`.

in order to populate the password you can't use `$form->populateValues($this->getRequest()->getPost())` to fill in the form element password value, zend will ignore this password element.

so after save you grab the password and pass it to the view directly `$viewModel->setVariable('pwd', $formData['userPassword']);` and pass it into the input element manually.

in your view element then

`<input type="password" value="<?php echo $this->pwd; ?>" name="userPassword" />`

but i don't recommend this procedure. the password should be a solid security wall, don't place a ladder infront of this wall.